# Bootstrap 5 open Modal from another Modal without closing first one

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am trying to open confirmation modal from modal without closing first one but it seems Bootstrap 5 has different behaviour than 4 version.

Below Bootstrap 4 version that works as expected

https://www.codeply.com/go/NiFzSCukVl

Below Bootstrap 5.1.2 version only difference with version 4 example is attributes are now data-bs instead of data-

https://www.codeply.com/p/imDoS33VZx

Is there any work around to solve this issue or am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried giving z-index 1051 to `.modal:nth-of-type(even)` selector and it worked in bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the modal with jQuery rather than using `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`, it will open the modal over an existing modal without closing the first one. Use this syntax:

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false,
  show: true
});

$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/):

> Toggle between multiple modals with some clever placement of the `data-bs-target` and `data-bs-toggle` attributes.

For example, you could toggle a password reset modal from within an already open sign-in modal.

**Please note that multiple modals cannot be open simultaneously** —this method simply toggles between two separate models."

Comment: I don't what they mean by opening simultaneously but to my mind , opening modal over modal is not a simultaneous operation